# PHP json_encode for Android Volley JsonObjectRequest return a JSONArray

Tags: php, android, android-volley, json

I want to send a JSONObject from a DB using PHP. 
The objective is to receive the object in an Android Volley, JsonObjectRequest and use it.

```
$manually=array(
    'w1' => "wall1.jpg",
    'w2' => "wall2.jpg",
    'w3' => "wall3.jpg",
    );

echo json_encode($manually); //send JSONobject  OK!!
```

When I create the array to put in json_encode "manually", my request receive a JSONObject and everithing is ok but, when I fill it using a loop, it is received a JSONArray ('attach the JSONObjectRequest error message').

```
$ar = array(); //empty array for  results
$loop =0;
            while($loop<mysql_num_rows($query)){                    //iterate for each row
                $ar["w".($loop+1)] = mysql_result($query, $loop, "img") ;   //associative array 
                $loop++;
            }
echo json_encode($ar); //JSONArray received
```

[image]

The result that I get in the webbrowser in both cases seems to be the same...
As far as i know, a JSONArray is the one with many JSONObjects, shaped like [{}{}], and I don't have [ ] brackets. How can I make PHP send a simple object and not an Array in my loop case?

[image]

Comment: If you want to get a JSONArray reponse from PHP server, in Android use JsonArrayRequest

Comment: I don't want, just want to get a JSONObject, but if I build the array with a loop Volley get an empty JSONArray []. Why?

Comment: Ok, try `parseNetworkResponse` in which `String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                            HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers, "utf-8"));` then post the jsonString you got

Comment: @Selvin: I think he will need to put that array into a jsonobject

Comment: `mysql_result($query, 0, "img")=="wall1.jpg" `// yes, TRUE

`'w1' => mysql_result($query, 0, "img") ` // Not working
  (ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value <br><table of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject)
 `'w1' => "wall1.jpg"` //works. It seems that when I use a variable to fill the matrix, the json_encode doesn't interpet it properly, and my server include some HTML in the response automatically...

Answer (score 1):

You could try to Wrap it all in an associative array with one element thats your array, and it could possibly be interpreted correctly:

```
echo json_encode(["walls" => $ar]);
```

Comment: `{"walls":{"w1":"wall1.jpg","w2":"wall2.jpg","w3":"wall3.jpg"}}` should be done like :`$a=array("walls" => $ar);` but still some HTML appears:            ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value <br><table of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: As of PHP 5.4 you can declare arrays like in my response. If you have html, its probably an error thats echoed by php. Check what that response is (its not json but plaintext)

Comment: I was geting an empty Object in Android.... My emulator appears in USA, and that was a constrain for the querry..

Comment: When passing an empty array to json_encode, it is send like a JSONArray , []. Then when I wraped all and manually set one element to some mysql_response($query, 0), I got the error message and could fix it.